# setContentView - strange behavior if not using R.id.?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my onCreate method for the first loaded Activity I have:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
final int splash = R.layout.splash;
setContentView(splash);
```

This causes the app to crash. But if I use:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

everything is fine.  What gives?

The only reason I am experimenting with this is because I want to load different layouts based on a set of data-driven options that will come from another class depending on the customer's choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a hard time believing that's actually causing the crash. Can you provide the exception?

Comment: I agree with brandon, I tested this code on my emulator, and it works perfectly fine... So you must have an issue somewhere else

Comment: I tried it again and it's working.  The first attempt at it must have been put together too early in the morning - so I think I was using the wrong type of resource ID like R.drawable.splash instead of the R.id.splash.  Thanks for creating sanity in my day. :^)

Comment: It's also possible you might have needed to do a Clean to get the R file to regenerate from the XML.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the other part of your code that's not pasted was trying to access resources of that content view BEFORE you had called `setContentView()`.